# How to change automatically the old routing style of Laravel to the new style in Laravel 9 with vscode?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, routes, find-replace

Hello I am facing a problem which is to change the old routing style of a laravel project to the new style. But due to the size of my routing file it will take me a lot of time to change all this. So I would like a sample regex code to use find/replace fonction into vscode to do it automatically.

Old style image :

[image]

Image new style wanted:

[image]

Comment: If you post images of text, make sure you also copy/paste or type the relevant content into the post directly. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to any images of text. Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using the find/replace function of vscode like this

[image]